# How does this example of recursion work? I keep getting a stack overflow error

Tags: java

This is the question 1. Write a recursive solution to divide an integer by another integer and provide the answer.  For example 35 / 7 = 5.

```
public class Division
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int a = 10;
         int b = 5;
         int answer = divide(a,b);
         return;
    }

    private static int divide(int a, int b)
    {
         int answer = a/b;

         return divide(a,b);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, when you use recursion, usually the very first line of the method should be "stop-condition". It's a condition when your method should stop calling itself recursively and return some not recursive result. Second, think about how to implement division without using division operation.

Comment: And another important thing about recursion - you should somehow change arguments (at least one) before recursive call. And this change should take you closer to your stop condition at each step - so recursion could end at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a stack overflow error because your recursive function `divide` doesn't have a *terminating condition* and will always call itself. A good recursive function has a terminating condition that breaks its self-calls.

I think the question has to do with subtracting `b` from the result until you reach negative value... Like for example 35 / 6,

```
35 
- 6 = 29 
     - 6 = 23 
          - 6 = 17
                - 6 = 11
                     - 6 = 5 - 6 = -1
```

You have to subtract 6 **five** times before it became negative so the answer is 5.

Something like...

```
private static int divide(int a, int b) {
  if (a - b < 0) { // or simply (a < b) 
    return 0;
  }

  return divide(a - b, b) + 1; 
  // +1 because I needed to count the number of times 
  // I've subtracted b from the running value.
}
```

Comment: `if (a < b)` is a little shorter.

Comment: Thanks, correct!  Wanted to use the negative condition to illustrate the algorithm of _getting to the point where it's negative_ but I've added it as a comment :)